# RequireJS Mismatch of parameters/callback

Tags: javascript, requirejs

COnsider the following example;

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"], function(dom){
    dom.byId("helloworld").innerHTML = "Hello New World!";
  });
```

My question is for the dependencies, while we refer 2 JS files, we just have one parameter as the callback (so assume it maps to the first dependent file)

But my question is what usage does it seem appropriate. Ideally I thought it should be always one-to-one mapped.

My question is not actually to understand about the DOJO usage...but I am looking to understand the Javascript concept behind the Mismatch of parameters/callback.

Answer (score 0):

The `dojo/domReady!` is a [loader plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html) that has the effect that the inner function is executed after the `DOMContentLoaded` event on the document - this makes sure that DOM elements are in place that you want to modify. So this dependency doesn't really have a value but only causes a side effect. It's essentially the same as if you would do this with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
require("dojo/dom", function (dom) {
    // Here the dom element I'm looking for is not guaranteed to
    // to be available ...
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // ... but here is
        dom.byId("helloworld").innerHTML = "Hello New World!";
    });
});
```